# Perform recursive file search and list file details for each found file?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm in Bash, that can be used on the CLI to perform a recursive file search and list the file details for each found file.

I'm not sure how to achieve this, I was thinking something in the following directon:

```
#recursive file search
alias ff='find . -type f -iname'

# List file details
alias ll='ls -al'
```

So I was wondering if I can somehow combine these commands, (e.g. `ff` recursive search and then perform `ll` on each result result output `O(n*n)`), but I hope there is a some simpler (pipe?) way to achieve the same result.

Comment: You can use `-exec` param: `find . -type f -exec ls -al {} \;`. Found file name will be substituted instead of `{}`, and `\;` means end of arguments for `-exec` param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx @Sam, I've come up with the following function which does what I want.

```
# recursive find files and list details
function ffdetails {
    find . -type f -name "$1" -exec ls -l {} +
}
```

Comment: Use quotes, and use `+`, and remove the `-a` option to `ls` (it's useless): `find . -type f -name "$1" -exec ls -l {} +` (with this, your files will be sorted and you'll have better formatting). You can try `-execdir` instead of `-exec` for a slightly different output (if your `find` supports it). Now, if your `find` supports it, you might consider using `-ls` instead: `find . -type f -name "$1" -ls`.

Comment: Thx @gni correted: removed -a (indeed useless) and added quotes to prevent reinterpretation of special characters. Added + for sorted formatting.